# Proof by Induction [Number Theory by George E. Andrews 1-1 #2]

Tags: number-theory, summation, induction

I am to use mathematical induction to prove that:

> $$1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + \cdots + n^3 = (1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n)^2 $$

Comment: Great! Then I think you should start doing it, now that we know your intentions!

Comment: Do you what Gauss did with the problem $1+\cdots+100$? XD

Answer (score -1):

Base case: if $n=1$ then $1^3=1^2$.

Induction step: you know that $$\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ So: $$1^3+\cdots+n^3+(n+1)^3=(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2+(n+1)^3$$ So all what remains is to prove that: $$(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2+(n+1)^3=(\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2})^2$$